# How to onfigure Log4Net to rolling everyday?

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to configure `Log4Net` to rolling every day, I mean i want it take log everyday in new file, so i config `Log4Net` like this in my `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
 <log4net>
   <root>
     <level value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
   </root>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="E:/MyLog_" />
  <staticLogFileName value="False" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy.mm.dd'.log'" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff} - %level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
 </appender>   
</log4net>
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

but it does not work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format appears to be incorrect. If they use the same [Date and Time Formatters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as Microsoft (I don't know if they do for sure, but they're fairly universal), then `mm` represents minutes, not days.

Per the [log4net documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender), try changing the lowercase `mm` to an uppercase `MM`.

```
<datePattern value="yyyy.MM.dd'.log'" />
```

Comment: I use it, because i want logs have name like this : MyLog_(date of system)

Comment: If i remove the patternstring and just write :                   <file  value="E:/MyLog_" />  in my App.config , it give me that fromat for the name of my logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DatePattern value="yyyy.MM.dd.lo\g" />
```

Comment: Since 'g' is a special character in date pattern we have to use like what i did or make it "yyyy.MM.dd'.log'"